# Why does my patch request only work if I submit it twice?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch-api

For background, I am making a help ticket system. The problem is with changing the status of a ticket to either close a ticket, or to re-open it. I am not getting any errors at all with the patch request, however the ticket isn't updating when I first send the patch request. But if I send two consecutive patch requests to change the same ticket, it will finally update the ticket. Here's the function I'm using.

```
const handleStatusChange = async () => {

    if (open){
        setOpen(false)
    } else if (!open){
        setOpen(true)
    }

    const ticket = {open: open}

    const response = await fetch(`/api/tickets/${previewTicket._id}`, {
        method: "PATCH",
        body: JSON.stringify(ticket),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
    })
    const json = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok){
        console.log(json.error)
    }
    if (response.ok){
        console.log("status has been changed", json)
    }
}
```

For now, I am not expected the UI of the ticket to change. I am planning on adding in React context to update it locally, so it doesn't have to fetch all of the tickets again. That being said, even if I check for any updates in MongoDB itself, nothing happens until I run the above function twice. I am almost positive that I could just use a for loop to send the request twice. But that seems a bit excessive, and I'm guessing there is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you mean the actual ticket UI isn't changing until you do it twice that's like related to the logic of rendering it, rather than the request itself. Can you add that code? And also the code itself, not a picture of it please

Comment: please add the code here [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). it would help us to understand the issue.

Comment: How are you verifying that the ticket isn't updating? I'd say this is most probably a server-side problem, either with accepting the request and running the update or how the response is formed.

Comment: please consider to add `try catch` in the function since you are using `async` function, you may got an error after that.